# Issues displaying table headings and contents horizontally using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I'm trying to display a table horizontally but I feel as though my counter is interfering with the layout of my table. The code works the way I want it to, it's just the design that's the problem at this stage

```js
var scores = [];

function enterScores(){

    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + (i));
    }
}

function displayScores(){
    
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = ("<tr>")

  for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += ("<th>Score " + i)
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += ("<td style='padding: 5px;'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center>");
  }
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += ("</tr>")
}

function Average(){
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i < scores.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(scores[i], 10);
  }

  var avg = sum/scores.length;
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("<b>Your score average is: </b>" + avg);
}
```

```html
  <input type="button" onclick="enterScores()" value="Enter Scores">
  <input type="button" onclick="displayScores()" value="Display Scores">
  <input type="button" onclick="Average()" value="Calculate Average">

  <br><br><font face="arial" size="2">
  
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="display"></table>
 <p id="average"></p>
```

Comment: using `innerHTML` is bad... and didn't respect `<Table>` html structure too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code, first all the data in a variable then insert in table.

```js
var scores = [];

function enterScores(){

    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + (i));
    }
}

function displayScores(){
    var data = ""; 
    var stringTh = "";
    var stringTd = "" ;

  for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
    stringTh += "<th>Score " + i + '</th>';
    stringTd += "<td style='padding: 5px;'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>";
  }
  data = "<tr>" + stringTh + "</tr>";
  data += "<tr>" + stringTd + "</tr>";
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = data;
}

function Average(){
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i < scores.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(scores[i], 10);
  }

  var avg = sum/scores.length;
  document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("<b>Your score average is: </b>" + avg);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="enterScores()" value="Enter Scores">
  <input type="button" onclick="displayScores()" value="Display Scores">
  <input type="button" onclick="Average()" value="Calculate Average">

  <br><br><font face="arial" size="2">
  
  <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="display"></table>
 <p id="average"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually creating another tbody within th and td every time you call it thats why its creating a new row every single time and making your data vertically aline. So here the code that I put everything in a DATA variable and call the "display" id once to write the values in html. Also you forgot to write closing tags on th and td so you actually need to fix it.

```
  function displayScores(){
  var Data;
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        Data = ("<th>Score " + i + "</th> <td style='padding: 5px;'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");  
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += ("<tr>"+ Data +"</tr>");
    }
  };
```

Also, you are calling the "display" id four times which is not a good thing for performance.

Answer (score 0):

for a start, better JS practice (+css), (should be improved)

```js
const TableDisplay     = document.getElementById('display')
    , bt_enterScores   = document.getElementById('enterScores')
    , bt_displayScores = document.getElementById('displayScores')
    , bt_Average       = document.getElementById('Average')
    , v_average        = document.getElementById('average-val')

var scores = [];

bt_enterScores.onclick=_=>
{
  for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + (i));
  }
}

bt_displayScores.onclick=_=>
{
  TableDisplay.innerHTML = null   // remove All table data

  let t_head  = TableDisplay.createTHead()
    , t_body  = TableDisplay.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))
    , refCell = 0

  t_head.insertRow(-1)
  t_body.insertRow(-1)

  scores.forEach((v,i)=>
  {
    t_head.rows[0].insertCell(refCell).innerText   = `Score ${i}`
    t_body.rows[0].insertCell(refCell++).innerText = v
  })
}

bt_Average.onclick=_=>
{
  let sum = 0;

  for(var i = 1; i < scores.length; i++){
    sum += parseInt(scores[i], 10);
  }

  v_average.textContent = `Your score average is: ${sum/scores.length}` 
}
```

```css
:root {
  --sz-font: 16px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--sz-font);
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#average-val {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--sz-font);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="enterScores"   >Enter Scores</button>
<button id="displayScores" >Display Scores</button>
<button id="Average"       >Calculate Average</button>

<br><br>

<table id="display"></table>

<p id="average-val"></p>
```